# always return to Login screen

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have an app start by `Splash activity screen` for 5 seconds Then open `Login activity screen` then after you put correct user and password open the `Menu activity (listActivity)` then each row click open `MyCity activity`.

**UPDATE:**

**What I'm trying to get is:** where ever you are in my app, and you go away from my app for any reason **not only when you press the home button** but also FOR EXAMPLES:

1. You press home button to check another app then want to return to my app .
2. You have notification show new message on whatsup or email, you open your whatsup or open email, then return to my app .

3- You left your mobile for period of time then you want to check my app again .

4- you press power button to close the phone ( lock the screen) , then open the lock and want to return back to my app .

what I mean any time you go away my app for any reason but whithout press **back back back** button which will exit the whole app 
then want to return again to my app must open to 
 you **the login screen** to re enter your usename and password again.

I Called `finish();` for both Splash activity and Login activity .

I tried:`android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in the Login activity in the manifest but it doesn'thing.

Any advice will be appreciated,

**PLEASE WRITE FULL WORKING CODE.**

LOGIN ACTIVITY:

```
 public class Login extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

     if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().
             toString().length() > 0 ) {
if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().
             toString().equals("test")) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
       finish(); }
            }   }               
                    });  }  }
```

Menu Activity :

```
  public class Menu extends ListActivity {

      String classes[] = { "City1", "City2", "City3", "City4", "City5"};

          @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
                                   }

     @Override
       protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
         String cheese = classes[position];
   try {
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.demo.MyCity");
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", cheese);
         startActivity(ourIntent);
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }}
```

MyCity Activity :

```
   public class MyCity extends Activity {
TextView tv1;
String city;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.city);  

    initializeTextViews();}

private void initializeTextViews() {

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_tv);
     city=getIntent().getStringExtra("cheese");

if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("City1")){

        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.city1)));}


    else if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("City2")){

        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.city2)));}


    else if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("City3")){

        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.city3)));}


    else if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("City4")){

        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.city4)));}


    else if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("City5")){

        tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.city5)));}


    }}
```

MY MANIFEST:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.demo.LOGIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.demo.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

              <activity
            android:name=".MyCity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.test.demo.MYCITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**SECOND UPDATE** : i reached halfway to what i want but still some steps i can't achieve it  explained as below :

BY applying  `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` to Splash activity ,

and prevent back button behaviour on Menu activity :

```
  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       moveTaskToBack(true);
       return true;
            }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                    } }
```

SO now when press home button away my app then return to my app its:

go directly to **Login activity**.

**but main goal now is :**

if :

**SCREEN LOCKED** when you are away from your  mobile , or press lightly the power button to lock the phone .

or

**OPENED MESSAGE** from notification

or

**OPENED EMAIL**  from notification

or

you have **CALL** and answer it ,

THEN return to my app **it does not go to login activity** but you will return to the page where you was befor .

ANY ADVICE PLEASE , THANKS.

**THIED UPDATE :**

i used another code for override home button and control the back button rather than appling :`android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` to Splash activity in manifest , just apply the down code to Menu activity:

```
     @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       moveTaskToBack(true);
         return true;}

    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
     Intent i=new Intent(Menu.this,Login.class);
       startActivity(i);
          finish();
        return true;}
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);}
```

Comment: you can't expect someone to write full working code. Suggestions and ideas will be given. You need to implement them in your way.

Comment: @Raghunandan , im still learning java and android development , i tried what i can do , others im asking about it to learn more and more , thanks for all .

Comment: May be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112329/how-to-make-splash-screen-not-to-load-if-app-is-already-in-memory

Comment: Is it me or are you asking to override Android's multitask/activities mentality/fundamentals/rules/design just to keep your app on foreground?..

Comment: @downvoter can you give me reason for down vote please.

Comment: You cannot force anybody to stare at your app's login screen. You can override everything except Home button **FOR THIS EXACT REASON**.

However, you can keep track of your current application's state and act accordingly in the overriden onBackPressed() to return to where you want. Home button will always work the way it works and you should give up on trying to change it's behaviour.

Comment: or just launch your Login activity() in the onResume() ?

Comment: @androidqq6 : check out my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868396/always-return-to-login-screen/13189099#13189099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the solution I came up with.](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/11/application-which-always-requires-login.html)

Please Download the project at the end of the blog post and test it.

Tested on:

- Samsung S3 running android 4.0.4
- Emulator running android 2.3.1

**The basic idea**: We will create a RequireLoginActivity which will be extended by all our activities except the LoginActivity.

Three cases should be captured when the *onResume* function is called:

1. Jumping from one RequireLoginActivity to another RequireLoginActivity using a flavor of startActivity.
2. Jumping from one RequireLoginActivity back to a previous RequireLoginActivity by finishing the current activity.
3. Coming back to a RequireLoginActivity after hiding it (we should here show the login!)

The basic idea of my solution is to have 2 counters: number of Started activities (**startCounter**) and number of Paused activities (**pauseCounter**). Each time an activity starts we will increment **startCounter**. Similarly, when an activity pauses, **pauseCounter** should be incremented. In our *onResume* function, we will decide whether to go to the Sign in by comparing the 2 counters. We will gotoLogin() if the 2 counters are equal!

Let me explain:
At any time, case 1 can be captured simply because upon starting new activities, our **startCounter** will always be greater that **pauseCounter** by 1. This is true because we will always have one extra activity started but not paused.

Also, case 3 is easily captured, because once you leave our app, say, using the HOME button, we will increment the **pauseCounter** and the 2 counters will become equal. Once the app is resumed, the *onResume* will decide to ***gotoLogin***().

Case 2 is a bit tricky, but simple as well. The trick is by overriding the *finish*() function and decrementing the **startCounter** once and the **pauseCounter** twice in it. Remember that when finishing the activity, *onPause* is called and our counters are equal. Now by decrementing **startCounter** once and **pauseCounter** twice, we ultimately returned to the counters' values of the previous activity, and **startCounter** will remain greater the **pauseCounter** by 1 when the previous activity resumes.

Comment: thnks alot sherif for your answer , i tyied you solution ,its overcome two things :1-press home button return to login activity .2- press power return to login activity which is good but still : 1- you recive call and answwer it then by back button you will be in second activity not login activity .2- you have notification that recived message or email and open it from notification bar then back button return you also to second activity not login activity as i wish , any advice regarding this two unsolved point , thanks my master

Comment: @androidqq6 I just downloaded the project I have in my blog. I tested it on a 2.3.1 emulator. When I get a phone call and return to my app, I get the login screen. Same thing happens when I leave the app and go to any notifications. Please download and test the sample project in http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/11/application-which-always-requires-login.html

Comment: i already did and tested on galaxy s 1 run gingerbread , it acts as i told you , tomorrow i will test it on galaxy s 3 run ice cream and reply back to you , thanks

Comment: ok its getting late here. I will try to fix this tomorrow maybe test it more. I'd like this to work (:

Comment: I have tested this on S3. Called the device and when the app resumed, it showed the login screen.

Comment: its work in ginger bread but im adjusting your code to my full project then i will reply you my friend , thanks

Comment: im try to apply your codes to my project ,regard Class AnotherActivity it required ( public class AnotherActivity extends RequireLoginActivity {) but my class has extends ListActivity as : (public class Menu extends ListActivity) and without write  RequireLoginActivity to refer to base class its not gave the needed behaviour so how to fix this .

Comment: simple solution: Copy `RequireLoginActivity` and create `RequireLoginListActivity`. change `RequireLoginListActivity extends Activity` to `RequireLoginListActivity extends ListActivity`. Now use `RequireLoginListActivity` instead of `ListActivity`

Comment: Good explanation and follow up.\

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib my friend im trying to apply your code but i have force close and error regard this :((RequireLoginApplication)getApplication()).reset();} . would you please help me , thanks

Comment: You need to add to your manifest `<application android:name="mobi.androidqq6.RequireLoginApplication">`. Use the correct name (:

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib yess when i recheck all your project i found that i miss this point coz my logcat point to ClassCastException now its ok , thanks my dear but actually i cant understand this point about ClassCastException and adding:  android:name=".RequireLoginApplication" to manifest , please can you explain it to me if you would ,thanks

Comment: Yes, each app has an Application class: This class is singleton, only one instance exists. You can override it, by creating a class that extends Application and specifying its name like I explained.

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib  my dear i create:public class RequireLoginListActivity extends ListActivity,my Menu Class i did:public class Menu extends RequireLoginListActivity,that ok Menu class return to Login Class when leave app but it cause problem which is when click any row to open MyCity activity its open but when you click back button to return to Menu it doesnot,it go directly to Login,

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib anther thing when apply RequireLoginListActivity to MyCity as:public class MyCity extends RequireLoginListActivity (MyCity class originally Activity not ListActivity) and run app then click any row in Menu Class to open MyCity Activity it gave force closeوthis logcat : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.demo/com.ttest.demo.MyCity}:java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'.please any advice,thanks

Comment: MyCity activity should extend RequireLoginActivity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19238/discussion-between-sherif-elkhatib-and-androidqq6)

Comment: @Sherifelkhatib you r right i create another class :RequiredLoginActivity and refer MyCity class to it and work fine i wll apply your code to rest of my project and forgive me if i will need more help from you my master sir .thanks

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you right, your goal is that users have to enter username and password again, when they come back to your App. So I think the most logical way to achieve this would be to add a check in all your Activities `onResume()` method to see if you have a username and password and if not, simply go to the login activity. Easiest way would be to have a BaseActivity implementing the check and let all your other activities (except for spash and login) inherit from that BaseActivity.

*in pseudo java code*

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!havingUsernameAndPassword()) {
            startActivity(loginActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }
}

class AnyOfYourActivitiesExceptSpashAndLogin extends BaseActivity {

    onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // ... further code
    }

    // ... further code
}
```

The implementation of `havingUsernameAndPassword()` of course depends on how you store the username and password in your login activity. A very simple way would be to store them in some static class members, so they'd survive as long as the Application runs.

**Update: a more concrete example**

I made a new example also showing how you can save the login data on login to be able to check it later on. Actually it would make even more sense to have just a flag 'loggedIn' and some user-id, but that depends upon your implementation, so I'll stick with username/password here.

```
class SimpleDataHolder {
    public static String username = null;
    public static String password = null;
}

class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    // ...
    // when user has entered valid username/password, store them in SimpleDataHolder:
    SimpleDataHolder.username = username;  // <-- store username entered
    SimpleDataHolder.password = password;  // <-- store password entered
}

class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (SimpleDataHolder.username == null || SimpleDataHolder.password == null) {
            startActivity(loginActivity); // <-- go to login
            finish();                     // <-- end current activity
        }
    }
}

class AnyOfYourActivitiesExceptSpashAndLogin extends BaseActivity {

    // ... your existing code (if any)

    onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // <-- this calls BaseActivity.onResume() which checks username/password
        // ... your existing code (if any)
}
```

Comment: please can you explain more with writing some more codes , thanks .

Comment: my dear friend i create BaseActivity as below :class BaseActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
  EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
   if(username.getText().toString().equals("test") && password.getText().toString().equals("test")) {
    

    Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();}}}}

Comment: regard the second part of your code (class AnyOfYourActivitiesExceptSpashAndLogin extends BaseActivity {
    onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // ... further code
    }
    // ... further code
}) , i will add it to all my classes exept login and splash class but what to write instead further code . sorry for sally question but have no experiance , thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood my suggestion a little bit. You shouldn't check EditText fields in the BaseActivity, as those probably will only exist in your LoginActivity. I meant, that you should store the username/password you get in your LoginActivity somewhere in your App, e.g. in static member variables, so you could access and check them in all the other Activities. I'll add a more concrete example to the answer.

Comment: @my dear sir , i have little experiance , i appreciate your help , if you explaine it by code i will be thankfull indeed my master

Comment: I added a more concrete example in my answer. Just had a closer look at the Logn activity you posted -- this cannot work mate. You check the input of username/password in your onCreate method, but when this method runs, the user had no chance yet to enter anything. You'll have to add some kind of button (e.g. Login) to your layout and check username/password when the user clicks that button.

Comment: my dear do you mean the new code you post here will be all in Login activity only , also i update my post with all project class please take alook on it , thanks

Comment: im sorry i think i cant do it by my self depend on my little experiance , thanks alot

Comment: What you want in your question (going back to Login when the device is locked or after a phone call, etc.) isn't good behaviour. You wouldn't want this of other apps, do you? You just have to remember that the user is logged in (and who he is), so the user who already has logged in can continue his work after receiving a  phone call or whatever. And to remember that a user is logged in, save this information in e.g. the SimpleDataHolder class I suggested. If you have so little experience with Android, maybe you should first do some simpler Apps without user authentication and stuff.

Comment: @Ridcully first of all i appreciate your endless help and support , second this app will be private ans will not publish , iknow its against the logic and customwr needs , last i will try and try with your code till it work with me , thanks indeed ,+1 upvote to your answer

Answer (score 4):

An application **CANNOT** re-route the home button without modifying the framework code. Sorry this is **NOT** possible...

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , please check the updeted post , thanks

Comment: @androidqq6 You simply can't -- and by design!

Answer (score 4):

To your second update problem I would suggest overriding the [OnResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method, but you must be careful with what you do in it. I would also suggest you study on how the [android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) works.

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion : 
Have a `key` in `SharedPreferences` called **exit**. In the `onCreate()` set the value of exit to **false**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle ..)
{
 SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("exit","false");
 editor.commit();
 .....  
}
```

then in `onResume()` check the value of **exit**. If it is true, take the user to the login screen else do not do anything .

```
public void onResume()
{
 super.onResume();
 SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 String exit=preferences.getString("exit","");
 if(exit.equals("true"))
 {
   Intent i=new Intent(this_activity.thi,login_activity.class);
   startActivity(i);
  finish()
 }
}
```

then in `onPause()` set the value of exit to **true**.

```
public void onPause()
{
 super.onPause();
 SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
     editor.putString("exit","true");
     editor.commit();
}
```

You said that you have taken care of the `backbutton`. Then this should do it. Your app will always return to the login screen.

Comment: thanks for your answer , im working to adjust some behaviour of my apk with your code , i will replay you later , thanks

Comment: @androidqq6 : yeah do replay, because I think it should work.

Comment: @ Ashwin when i test your code lets say 4 times , first when press home button in Menu activity then return to my app then press power button in Menu activity to lock screen then return to my app and again for second activity so we pause and resume 4 times , finally my question : im now in Login activity (if i press back button it must exit the app but actually it shift me to Login screen 4 times before it exit app , any advice my friend , thanks

Comment: which mean resume methoid after calling Login activity which start second activity (Menu) , it didnot finish the login activity it self after start the second activity

Comment: @androidqq6 : what happened when you pressed the home button and came back? did it go to the login screen or the original activity?

Comment: it go to Login but if you are in Login screen and press back the normal action is exit the app but its not by back it go to anther login screen then another login screen and so on till exit the app

Comment: @androidqq6 : ok..then in your manifest add this to your login_screen activity - android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19018/discussion-between-ashwin-and-androidqq6)

Comment: @androidqq6 : see the chat, I have given you a code. It worked for me. I tried pressing the home button and backbutton and power button in menu activity and in all cases, next time login screen was shown . Try to paste the same code.

Comment: i past it , we have two issue , 1- when you are in menu and press home button or power button or you get message in notification it exit the app i want it to go directly to login activity when i return to my app again not exit , 2- apply same code to second activity when home button or power pressed it return to menu activity not login , thanks any advice

Comment: @androidqq6 : isn't login your first activity? the activity that is shown when the icon is pressed?

Comment: Splash is first which is LAUNCHER

Comment: @androidqq6 : oh..then wait I will try something else.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround will be to create a activity(FinisherActivity) and call finish() in its onCreate() method. Then whenever you need to finish a activity on pressing the home button or back button and prevent it from staying on the stack just use an Intent to call FinisherActivity . But remember to setFlags for the intent to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP...I know its not an efficient approach, but it should work..

Answer (score 1):

Actually I dont think i'm sure what exactly your asking,  Do you want to press the Home Key built into your android device and start an activity?

[Homekey listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME)

Try This:
if it works then awesome, just through an intent in there to call your login activity

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home Key is pressed
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Didnt work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(e);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the home button default behaviour. You achieve the desired result by clicking back button, Home button's default behaviour is to goto Home Screen. My suggestion Override Back Button. Then using intent and setting flags properly you can goto login screen.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        Intent i= new Intent("yourpackage.login"); 
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); 
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        break;  
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Intent i= new Intent("yourpackage.Login");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); startActivity(i);finish(); Do this on Key Down. Clear all Activities goto login screen. This should help you.

Comment: NOTHING HAPPEN , maybe i miss some thing in writting my code regarding your answer , would you please update it with full working code also i will update my post with login activity , thanks alot

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , please check the updeted post , thanks

Comment: 1)http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html. Please go through the note at he end.2) You need to know how to manage your activity lifecycle. 3)http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.3)http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. Go through the links especially the last one. I am sure it will help you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html. Here's the link. Also have a look at this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: android:noHistory=["true" | "false"]. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html. Activity has no history in the stack if its true. Depending on your need define the same in manifest. Hope the above links will help you.

Comment: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/09/05/how-to-override-back-home-button-in-an-android-app/. This might help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18698/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-androidqq6)

Answer (score 1):

what you are asking is against the way that android works .

when the user presses the home button , he expects that when he returns to the app , everything will stay as it was before , unless he wasn't there for a long time or if he ran a resource consuming app .

it's as if on windows , when you click ALT+TAB , you won't expect to see login on the email client (or messenger , or whatever app you use) .

in any case , you can use onWindowFocusChanged together with any of the [functions of activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (onResume,onStart,onRestart,onPause,onStop,...) , and handle only the relavant cases you wish to use .

Comment: im fully agree with you but this app will not publish , its private app to me and i need to do that , would you please write some code to achieve that please , coz im new in android development , thanks

Comment: investigate the events i've written about (write in the logs if you wish) , and capture the scenario that you wish to handle , and then add the logic you want...

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , please check the updeted post , thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible because the home button is exclusive to call launcher application, but you can do your app a launcher application, running in kiosk mode for example, see [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android) and [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625413/is-it-posible-to-use-a-device-to-run-one-application-exclusively).

to turn a activity on launcher activity add this on itentfilter on manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , please check the updeted post , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct: to clear the activity stack when launching your application, you should add `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` **to your root activity**, which is `Splash`, not `Login` (it will be the first one running, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460981/cleartaskonlaunch-howto) on determining the root activity)!

From the [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear)

> This attribute is meaningful only for activities that start a new task
>   (the root activity); **it's ignored for all other activities** in the
>   task.

So if you move the attribute in the manifest from `Login` to `Splash`, it should work, your application will always start with the splashscreen.

**UPDATE:** To restart your app even on incoming calls, screen lock or notifications, you have to add `android:noHistory="true"` (docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)) to all your other activities, or call `finish()` in all their `onPause()` methods.

*It's worth mentioning that our answers are so different and complicated because what you want to achieve is totally against core Android concepts (for example, [here](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html) is a good article on exiting apps), so really, don't do anything like this outside your private app.*

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , please check the updeted post , thanks

Comment: you are right i applied android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" to splash in manifest and prevent back botton in Menu activity and removed finish(); from login activity so i get half way to my need the rest you CAN check it in my SECOND UPDATE , PLEASE,THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are asking, however I believe this is what you are looking for: [How to make splash screen not to load if app is already in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112329/how-to-make-splash-screen-not-to-load-if-app-is-already-in-memory) . To summarize my post there:

This is a design problem. Your launcher activity should not be your splash screen activity. Instead, open your splash activity in your main activity's onCreate method. That way, if it is opened fresh, onCreate is called and the splash screen is shown. Otherwise, if the app is merely resumed, which calls onResume, there would be no call to open the splash screen activity.

Then you can change your manifest to this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"/>
```

Comment: my problem not in reload splash screen , i want any time you left my app by any reason mentioned above in my post and you want to return to my app , it force you to Login screen to re enter user name and password each time , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) activity attribute (for each of your activities) in the Android Manifest? That sounds like exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `finish()` in all your activities' `onPause()` methods except Login activity. And you can call `startActivity(new Intent (this, LoginPage.this))` in their `onResume()` method. So whenever the activities will come to foreground, user will be redirected to Login page again.

Answer (score 0):

My little efforts may helps you, I had successfully Override the `HOME` button(below Android 4.0)

You can mould the code according to your requirement.

[**Answer on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904)

[**Source at GITHUB**](https://github.com/hotveryspicy/OverrideHomeButton)

As you can now handle Home button so you can easily create your own logic to perform you Application flow.

this is you targetted event

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if ( (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) && isLock) {
             //Logic when Home button pressed
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Hoping this will definitely going to meet our requirements.

*Note: All this is for capturing `Home` Button for others you can manage*

Comment: thanks alot for your answer i already test it , it override the home button , great , but as you saw in my SECOND UPDATE i already solve the problem of home button , but others issues i cant , tried with onpause(); methoid but i cant get it , i agree it my be simple for others but for me with no  experience in jave or android coz in just starting  learning  java nowadays, any more advice my friend , thanks

Comment: downvote for KEYCODE_HOME the Logic when Home button pressed will never be executed (but back in 2012 it was a solution - just want to indicate that the code is outdated)

Comment: @MartinPfeffer Agree, but it was working in earlier version of Android, I stated `I had successfully Override the HOME button(below Android 4.0)`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904)